# How to count number of lines when using timeout

Tags: bash, cygwin

I would like to run code that outputs text lines and count the number it outputs in 120 seconds.

```
timeout 120 foo|wc -l
```

does not work though as `wc -l` never gets run.

What's the right way to do this?

---

**Update**

The problem is entirely to do with cygwin it seems. `timeout 120 foo > temp.txt` creates an empty file.

**Update 2**

```
timeout --foreground 1 find / | wc -l
```

does work. But `timeout --foreground 1 ./a.exe|wc -l` returns `0`.

Why would that be?

Comment: Does your `timeout` have a `--preserve-status` flag?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes it does

Comment: Hardly matters, though -- `wc -l` never sees the exit status of whatever's piped into it.

Comment: @eleanora, the claim that "wc -l never gets run" is very improbable. All parts of a pipeline are invoked at the same time -- so `wc -l` gets started at the same time `timeout` does.

Comment: By the way: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231526/79307

Answer (score 0):

Use --foreground option with timeout:

```
timeout --foreground 1 cat file|wc -l
```

from man:

```
--foreground   when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
               allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
               in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
```

P.S.
if i have .cpp file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
for(long long i=0;i<1000000000000;i++)
cout<<i<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

compile:

```
g++ a.cpp
```

and now:

```
timeout --foreground 1 ./a.out|wc -l
```

output:

```
991097
```

Comment: Hmm.. it almost works.timeout  1 ./a.exe
1
2
3
[...]

Comment: timeout --foreground 1 ./a.exe |wc -l
0

Comment: In  other words... it doesn't seem to work  as it outputs 0 where it should be a bigger number.

Comment: strange. a.exe print any line during 1 sec?

Comment: Yes it prints the lines "1" "2" and "3" etc.

Comment: I'm unclear on why you think `--foreground` is needed here. `wc -l` *isn't* a child of `timeout`; it's a sibling, started by the parent shell at the same time.

Comment: It seems to be a cygwin problem with pipes.  See my update.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `children of COMMAND will not be timed out`

Comment: @tso, correct, but the process on the other side of a pipeline from something is a sibling, not a child. So verbiage that speaks only to children has nothing to do with anything here.

Comment: I could conceive of `timeout` doing something weird that *does* involve other siblings, but the documentation you quote certainly doesn't substantiate such behavior.

Comment: so, if pipeline is sibling and not child, why it works?

Comment: As I said above, "I could conceive of `timeout` doing something weird" -- would need to read its source to see *why* it's impacting processes that aren't actually its children, if it is in fact doing so. That they're not its children, though, is something you can easily prove yourself: `{ timeout 10 sleep 20 | sleep 30; } & sleep 1; pstree $$`, and you'll see that the only child of `timeout` is `sleep 20`, whereas the line to `sleep 30` is drawn from the parent shell that itself spawned `timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly convoluted solution, but one that works on my primitive version of `timeout` which does not support any of the normal flags, is to use an intermediate file:

```
F=$(mktemp)
timeout 120 foo > "${F}"
wc -l "${F}" | cut -d ' ' -f1
rm "${F}"
```

The `cut` command is there just to remove the name of the tempfile from the output of `wc`. It is optional otherwise.

#### Update in response to OP's update:

Given that some convoluted combination of pipes and buffering is at fault here, the [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/231527/79307) offered by a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231526/79307) on [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) may be the answer here:

```
( timeout 10 foo || true ) | wc -l
```

By isolating `timeout` in a separate subshell and adding `|| true`, you ensure that the termination signal to `foo` will never affect `wc`. The buffering issues that prevented the output file from being generated in my original attempt should not affect the pipe (probably?).

#### Final Suggestion

Since buffering *does* seem to be an issue here, you could try to use the `--preserve-status` flag for `timeout` it may prevent the command from being terminated in a way that deletes the output.

Comment: It seems to be a cygwin problem with pipes.  See my update.

Comment: @eleanora. I think I found the correct answer, will update.

Comment: @eleanora. Try the new version.

Comment: Still doesn't work! I think this needs someone with cygwin as there is clearly something odd going on.

Comment: @eleanora. I think that Cygwin just gets rid of the buffered output if the command is terminated. Do you have the `expect` package installed? It contains a tool `unbuffered` that may be helpful here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25375/79307

Comment: `stdbuf` is much lighter-weight than `unbuffer`.

Comment: I have stdbuf. I installed `expect` too but I just read https://superuser.com/questions/840903/shell-unbuffering-for-cygwin-is-it-possible . Maybe I doomed.

Comment: @eleanora. I have to admit, it's not looking good for you right now.

Comment: @eleanora. Are you the admin on your machine? Can you set up a Linux VM?

Comment: Yes I have a Linux VM

Comment: I think your best bet would be to run on the VM then. It will be more predictable and you shouldn't experience this weird issue there.

Comment: @eleanora. I made a final update. If `--preserve-status` does not work, I think the VM is your best bet.